# WiX Compile Time Directory Harvesting And Variables

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm a bit confused about the interaction of these tools at the moment and I need a little helping ironing out my appraoch (or being told I'm being daft).

I have a VS2010 solution with two WiX projects.  I have a a `.WXI` file in a solution folder that contains a number of global variables that I would like to use in multiple projects (more will be added in the future).

I include the `.WXI` file in my main `Product.wxs` project using the standard syntax like this:

```
<?include ..\Shared\Common.wxi?>
```

This is working great and all the variables are available.  However as part of this build process I also need to run `heat.exe` in order to generate a large fragment automatically on each rebuild.

I use a command like this:

```
"Heat.exe" dir %sourcedir% -sfrag -sreg -suid -gg -ke -template fragment -out %wixfile% -dr INSTALLFOLDER -cg MyInstall -var var.MyFileSource
```

In my included variables file I have this:

```
<?define MyFileSource= "$(var.SolutionDir)..\..\..\..\mydir\bindist" ?>
```

However I get an error like this:

```
Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.MyFileSource)'.
```

As you would expect as the fragment file does not contain a line that references the file `Common.wxi` but the problem is this fragment file is going to be replaced each build prior to compilation so it's completely inpractical to hand edit this fragment in order to add it each time (not to mention impossible anyway).

My question is am I approaching this completely incorrectly?  If not, what is the best way to get this working correctly?

What is confusing is that there is the `-var` switch to create a variable reference in the fragment file but no way to then enable the variable referencing from an include file (unless I've missed that somewhere in the docs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of placing the variables in a separate `wxi` file and include it in all possible places, you can supply `candle.exe` with the variables you need. You can do this either from command line (using `-dVarName=VarValue` syntax), or with any of the supported build tools, NAnt or MSBuild.

I can see the following advantages:

- the WiX authoring are not polluted with `<?include?>` stuff here and there
- you don't have to mess the heat harvested authoring
- variables defined once from the command line are available in any `wxs` file of your project

Comment: I've been looking to doing this today and so far the information I have found ([link]http://badecho.com/2011/09/automating-wix-with-msbuild/) is this still the way to go with this or is there a better way with newer versions of WiX (I'm using 3.8)?

Comment: Well, I think that's a valid sample. The official manual contains the description of `Candle` task, which also accepts the list of preprocessor variables: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/candle.html

Answer (score 0):

I also have such an include-file that centralizes my configuration during the build. As I also use variables in the files produced by heat this is very convenient, as I have to define them just once.
To be able to use these variables also in the heat-output you can transform the output created by heat using a xslt-transformation. Just add `-t myTransformFile.xslt` to the command-line of heat, so the output will be transformed according to the stylesheet defined in `myTransformFile.xslt`.

In the `myTransformFile.xslt`-file just add the following, which will basically copy everything and also add the `Include`-directive:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
        exclude-result-prefixes="wix">

        <xsl:template match="wix:Wix">
          <xsl:copy>
            <!-- The following enters the directive for adding the Common.wxi include file to the dynamically generated file -->
            <xsl:processing-instruction name="include">$(sys.CURRENTDIR)..\Shared\Common.wxi</xsl:processing-instruction>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

You have to adjust the path to your `Common.wxi` of course so that it can be found at build-time.

Edit: forgot a part of the XSLT-file that copied also other elements.